# How do I add something in a Dictionary?

Tags: python, json

I have a dictionary inside of another dictionary in a Json file.
The File(highscore_history.txt):

```
{
    "Highscores": {
        "0highscore": 2
    }
}
```

Now I want to add something into the second dictionary...

```
with open("highscore_history.txt", "w") as Highscore_history_txt:
    highscore_history["Highscores"].update({f"{last_element_of_the_history}highscore": main_game.current_highscore[-1]})
    json.dump(highscore_history["Highscores"], Highscore_history_txt, indent =4)
    saved_highscores = {f"{last_element_of_the_history} highscore": main_game.current_highscore[-1]}
```

but if I do it this way the file changes but the new pair is printed outside of the second dict:

```
{
    "Highscores": {
        "0highscore": 2
    },
    "1highscore": 0,
}
```

So how can I make it, that the new key value pair gets also into the second dictionary?

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you claim happens: Your code only saves the inner dict to your `Highscore_history_txt` file. I get this in the file: `{"0highscore": 2, "1highscore": 0}`. Why do you not do: `json.dump(highscore_history, Highscore_history_txt, indent =4)` since this would update the file so it is ready to be reloaded later?

Comment: i need the second dictionary because i want to add another dictionary independent from the otherone later

Comment: What `"second dictionary"`?

Comment: It would be much easier to answer this question (and determine what exactly you're asking) with a [mre]. This code shown can't be run as-is, so we can't test it without defining all the missing variables ourself, which will only be guesses.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Short example of how to write new data to JSON-file.
Still same concept.

JSON before run:

```
{
  "Highscores": {
    "0highscore": 2
  }
}
```

Code:

```
import json

​
def write_json(data):
    with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
​
​
with open('data.json') as json_file:
        data = json.load(json_file)
        
data['Highscores']['1highscore'] = 0
write_json(data)
```

​

JSON after run:

```
{
  "Highscores": {
    "0highscore": 2,
    "1highscore": 0
  }
}
```

​
​
​
​
​

Comment: Doesnt make a change, the new file is still:    "Highscores": {
        "0highscore": 2
    },
    "Times": {},
    "1highscore": 0,
    "2highscore": 0,
    "3highscore": 0,
    "4highscore": 0,
    "5highscore": 0,
    "6highscore": 0,
    "7highscore": 0
} But luckily these are the baseics huh xD

Comment: Yeah, since you are working with another file you need to use json.dump() https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/